Is removing 'Info.plist' file the right solution to 'Multiple commands produce '/Info.plist' duplicate output file'?
I duplicated one of my xcode projects where I was using CoreData to explore it's functionality with other database options, I changed the name on the duplicate and left the original file as it was. When I tried to run/build the duplicate application I ended up with this error message:
/Users/UserName/Desktop/IOS/ProjectName/ProjectName.xcodeproj The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/UserName/Desktop/IOS/Project/ProjectName/Info.plist'.
I removed the working files from Project Navigator and added them back, still had the same problem.
After 2 days of browsing into StackOverflow (thank you for the help! Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce & Problems after upgrading to Xcode 10: Build input file cannot be found), I found the solution that worked for me but I'm not 100% that it is the RIGHT one, the app works so I'm happy for it, but it was a combination of different solutions I found. Here is what worked for me:
In Xcode:
Project Navigator > Project Name > Targets > ProjectName > Identity > Added Version and Build (1.0 and 1 in each of them)
Then:
Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources > Removed Info.plist
Then:
Targets > Build Settings > Packaging >
Generate Info.plist File > Yes
and
Info.plist File > Add the NEW path to the plist file (in my case: ProjectNamee/Info.plist)
Then:
Erase all contents and settings - Simulator
Clean Build Folder - Xcode
And it worked...
Also, I realized that in Build Settings my project was already linking the plist file, so I decided to remove it from the Project Navigator and still works (not recommended).
Any help on why this worked? I really need to understand the why/how/what on everything...
Thank you very much!
P.D: I understood that somehow a second reference to the Info.plist file was created. Is there a way to correct that so it doesn't happen again when we try to duplicate a project?
